# How do I tween two positions with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, animation, tween

If I have the following markup:

```
<ol class='source'>
  <li id='1'>first</li>
</ol>

<ol class='target'>
  <li id='2'>second</li>
</ol>
```

How do I use jQuery to 'tween' animate moving `li#1` to `ol.target`. I can imagine how to do this in a raw way with `$.animate`, but I may be re-inventing the wheel. This seems like a common enough use case that I'm just missing part of the API or a plugin.

How would you do this?

Comment: Is target in the same place on your page all the time or could it be in a different position based on other content?

Comment: @Catfish the location of target is dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. insert a placeholder `span` right before the item you want to tween (`insertBefore`)
2. insert the content item into its new position (`appendTo`)
3. store the new height, width, and offset (`height`, `width`, `offset`)
4. return the original content item to its place after the placeholder (`insertAfter`)
5. animate the height, width, and offset to the new values
6. when the animation is complete, insert the content item to its new position again
7. ???
8. profit

Comment: This is pretty close to the raw way I was imagining. Should be pretty easy to abstract into a plugin, though I was hoping one already existed. Ty for the pseudo.